# Hibernate Criteria for map of basic type

Tags: java, hibernate, collections, mapping

I have a Hibernate mapping that looks something like this:

```
class A {
    private Long id;
    private Map<C,String> someMap;
    ...

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long getId() {
         return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
         this.id = id;
    }

    @ElementCollection(targetClass=String.class, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    public Map<C, String> getSomeMap() {
        return someMap;
    }

    pubic void setSomeMap(Map<C,String> someMap){
           this.someMap = someMap;
    }
}

class B {
    private Long id;
    private A a;
    ...
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long getId() {
         return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
         this.id = id;
    }

    @OneToOne
    public A getA(){
         return a;
    }

    public void setA(A a){
         this.a = a;
    }
}

class C {
    private Long id;
    ...
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long getId() {
         return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
         this.id = id;
    }
}
```

How can I do a query (with criteria) to get all "В" which have such "A" which have, for example, "test" as value in "someMap"? Or can I do it only with clear sql?

Comment: You should post details about your mapping. Either post your hbm.xml file or the annotations used for the mapping.

Comment: Updated information about mapping.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. I've never done a map where key is the object, and string the value. Generally it's the other way around. Can you keep the string on C, and use a straight collection? Or is there a funky many to many relationship going on here?

Comment: Using Map<Object,String> is routine case, I use this way fairly often. In my case - keeping String in C unacceptable. And now I have some problem with query, because String is not Entity, so I can put it in criteria as Restriction. I founded one way to solve my problem - it's wrap my String in Entity class, and then write pretty criteria, but I want to solve it without wrapping. How can I do it?